# Windows folder and User folder only 10% of disk usage

Tags: windows, hard-drive

My Users folder and the Windows folder, actually all my files together are suppossedly 123 Gb. The "pie" graphic at Hard Disk properties says, I'm using almost 500Gb.
I know there's some people that had a similar problem, but all I found on the web or here, is something like "All my files together make 60 Gb and the pie says I use 75"... I think this isn't my case (in my case it is almost five times a difference!!)

Answer (score 1):

The only logical conclusion is, that your method of viewing the files is not correct. Perhaps there are hidden files, or you have files in your recycle bin.

In order to be sure, download a tool that will show you where files taking up space. To name a few: [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/), or [Tree Size Free](http://www.jam-software.com/freeware/).

Both are free to use and will tell you where files are taking up space. Administrative rights are required to get an accurate reading because then it can scan inside folders where you don't have rights, such as windows folders, protected system folders and user accounts that are not yours.

Once done, you'll see that there is 500GB in use and you'll see where it is located.